# Непрерывный обмен сообщениями клиент-сервера на сокетах

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

Есть задача: необходимо организовать непрерывное (без закрытия сокета) общение клиента с сервером через сокеты. Проблема возникла в том, что я не знаю, как считать из сокета сразу всё содержимое сообщения, т.к. есть такие условия:

1. Общение происходит непрерывно (т.е. никто не закрывает сокет сам)
2. Клиент может посылать серверу сообщения неограниченной длины
3. Сервер должен считать всё, что отправил клиент и интерпретировать
   это, как одно сообщение

Рассмотрим, например, просто эхо-сервер. Есть такая реализация:

```
import socket
from multiprocessing import Process

def processing(connection):
    while True:
        incoming = b""
        while True:
            incoming += connection.recv(1)
            if not incoming or incoming[-1] == 0:
                break
        if not incoming:
            exit(0)
        connection.send(incoming)

def main():
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.bind(("", 9090))
    sock.listen(5)
    while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        print("New connection from {}".format(addr))
        proc = Process(target=processing, args=(conn,))
        proc.daemon = True
        proc.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    exit(0)
```

Т.е. сейчас у меня сообщения условно ограничиваются байтом `0`, но при такой реализации, если клиент отправит, например, `b"\x01\x00\x02\x00"`, то это проинтерпретируется как 2 разных сообщения (`b"\x01\x00"` и `b"\x02\x00"`), а необходимо, чтобы интерпретировалось, как одно (`b"\x01\x00\x02\x00"`).

Натыкался, что сокет можно установить в такой "режим", что если попытаться читать из пустого сокета, то сработает исключение и думал как-то использовать это, но не думаю, что это правильно.

Comment: И как программа должна определять, что 0 в одних случаях разделяет сообщения, а в других не разделяет? Придумайте более адекватное разделение - например, перед сообщением пишите его длину в байтах. Режимы тут вообще ни при чём

Comment: @andreymal Она не должна этого определять. Я показал свою реализацию, где я конец сообщения обозначил 0, но она меня не устраивает, ибо, как я сказал, мне необходимо, чтобы сообщение, типа `b"\x01\x00\x02\x00"`, воспринималось как одно. Насчёт сначала передавать размер - см. 2.

Comment: Ещё раз: придумайте более адекватное разделение. Например, перед сообщением пишите его длину в байтах. Если сообщение может быть неограниченной длины — объявите концом сообщения кусок нулевой длины. А все предыдущие куски единого неограниченного сообщения посылайте с указанной длиной — они ведь абсолютно точно известны перед отправкой. Именно так работает [chunked transfer encoding](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) в HTTP, например

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо! Можете оформить второй комментарий, как ответ?

Comment: И да, фраза «сразу всё содержимое» в контексте сокетов совершенно непонятна. Пока сокет открыт, отправитель может продолжать отправлять бесконечно много данных, и момент, когда будет доступно «сразу всё содержимое», не наступит никогда, пока сокет не закроют.

Comment: У меня такое чувство, что вы в списке условий забыли указать что-то вроде «Общение производится посредством обмена сообщениями, которые в сокете нужно как-то разделить друг от друга» — с таким пунктом вопрос стал бы намного понятнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В TCP не предусмотрено никакого разделения на сообщения, так что его придётся придумать самостоятельно. Если в сообщении может быть нулевой байт и он не может быть разделителем сообщения, придётся придумывать более хитрое разделение — например, указывать длину сообщения. Если сообщение может быть произвольной длины и она заранее не известна, придётся придумывать ещё более хитрое разделение — например, слать сообщение кусками определённой длины, а концом сообщения считать кусок нулевой длины.

Заведём вспомогательную функцию, которая читает из сокета ровно столько байт, сколько запрошено:

```
def readexactly(connection, bytes_count):
    b = bytearray()
    while len(b) < bytes_count:
        part = connection.recv(bytes_count - len(b))
        if not part:
            raise IOError("Соединение закрыто")
        b += part
    return bytes(b)
```

А вот функция, которое читает из сокета сообщение по кускам до тех пор, пока не придёт кусок нулевой длины. За длину при этом считаются первые два байта в big endian (то есть длина одного куска не более 65 килобайт), но само сообщение может быть сколь угодно длинное, пока оперативки хватает:

```
def read_message(connection):
    b = bytearray()
    while True:
        part_len = int.from_bytes(readexactly(connection, 2), "big")
        if part_len == 0:
            # Прислали кусок нулевой длины — сообщение закончено
            break
        # Прислали кусок ненулевой длины — добавляем к сообщению
        b += readexactly(connection, part_len)
    return bytes(b)
```

Если отправить в сокет `b"\x00\x06hello \x00\x06world!\x00\x00"`, то эта функция прочитает и вернёт `hello world!`