# Отправка, принятие и сохранение больших файлов через socket в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, сокет

Учусь сейчас отправлять данные через сокеты. И процессе столкнулся со следующей ошибкой: не получается отправить файл размером 5 мегабайт через сокет (вот ссылка на файл: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/Galaxies_of_the_Infrared_Sky_.jpg). Файлы меньше 1 мегабайта отправляются без ошибок. Проблема появляется при чтении данных, переданных клиентом серверу. Сервер, по непонятным причинам, не может выйти из цикла в `reliable_receive`, и программа как будто зависает. Подскажите в чем проблема? Ниже код.

UPD: Я обновил код, воспользавшись ответом в комментариях (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/982881/324059), но это как-то не работает. Пишет - `TypeError: cannot convert 'NoneType' object to bytes` в строке `part_len = int.from_bytes(self.readexactly(2), "big")` в коде клиента. Помогите, что делать?

Код сервера (отправляет клиенту название файла, который он должен отправить серверу, затем сохраняет этот файл):

```py
import socket
import json
import base64


class Listener:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        listener.bind(('', port))  # IP
        listener.listen(0)
        print('[+] Waiting for incoming connection...')
        self.connection, address = listener.accept()
        print('[+] Got a connection from ' + str(address))

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data.encode())

    def readexactly(self, bytes_count):
        b = b''
        while len(b) < bytes_count:
            part = self.connection.recv(bytes_count - len(b))
            if not part:
                return b
            b += part

    def reliable_receive(self):
        b = b''
        while True:
            part_len = int.from_bytes(self.readexactly(2), "big")
            if not part_len:
                return json.loads(b)
            b += self.readexactly(part_len)

    def execute(self, command):
        self.reliable_send(command)
        return self.reliable_receive()

    def write_file(self, path, content):
        with open(path, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(base64.b64decode(content))
            return '[+] Download successful'

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = input('>> ')
            result = self.execute(command)
            result = self.write_file(command, result)
            print(result)


my_listener = Listener('192.168.0.10', 4444)
my_listener.run()
```

Код клиента(получает название файла от сервера и отправляет серверу этот файл):

```py
import socket
import json
import base64


class Client:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connection.connect((ip, port))

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data.encode())

    def readexactly(self, bytes_count):
        b = b''
        while len(b) < bytes_count:
            part = self.connection.recv(bytes_count - len(b))
            if not part:
                return b
            b += part

    def reliable_receive(self):
        b = b''
        while True:
            part_len = int.from_bytes(self.readexactly(2), "big")
            if not part_len:
                return json.loads(b)
            b += self.readexactly(part_len)

    def read_file(self, path):
        with open(path, 'rb') as file:
            return base64.encodebytes(file.read()).decode("utf-8")

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = self.reliable_receive()
            command_result = self.read_file(command)

            self.reliable_send(command_result)


my_client = Client('192.168.0.9', 4444)
my_client.run()
```

А еще эти decode, encode, base64... я успел запутаться в них миллион раз, пока писал код. Хотелось бы понять также, как, и можно ли вообще упростить это?

Comment: А зачем Вам `base64`? Чем Вас незакодированные байты не устраивают? Для передачи больших файлов советую посмотреть [Chunked transfer encoding](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), пример реализации можете посмотреть в [ответе @andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/982881/324059).

Comment: Он нужен, чтобы передавать его в json. Ваш код, кстати, не очень работает. Объясните, в чем проблема?

Comment: Какой мой код? Своего кода я не приводил. Для передачи `json`, думаю, Вам подойдёт модуль `pickle`, т.к. он умеет сериализовывать некоторые типы (в т.ч. `dict` и `str`) в байты и обратно.

Comment: Да, я подумаю над этим. И все же, вы можете предположить, почему код не работает?

Comment: Я не понимаю, о каком коде Вы говорите.

Comment: Я изменил код в вопросе, я про него

Comment: *>>TypeError: cannot convert 'NoneType' object to bytes* - Потому что Вы ничего не возвращаете из функции `readexactly()` (если функция ничего не возвращает, то она возвращает `None` неявно) после выхода из `while`.

Comment: Что-ж. Я исправил это. Однако теперь у меня та же ошибка - программа зависает на `part = self.connection.recv(bytes_count - len(b))`. Видимо, условие `not part` никогда не может быть исполнено, т.к. `recv` все время ждет, когда ему будет отправлено хоть что-нибудь. Как быть?

Comment: Вы решили использовать **Chunked transfer encoding**, но почему Вы из этого механизма взяли только чтение? Правильную отправку кто будет делать? Передаваемые данные надо разбить на куски какой-то длинны (например, по 65535 байт, раз Вы на принимающей стороне считываете длину куска как 2 байта), затем отправлять последовательности `(длина куска):(кусок этой длинны)`, конец передачи обозначается длиной куска 0. Вас никто не заставляет использовать именно этот механизм, Вы можете придумать что-то своё, если с этим возникают трудности.

Comment: Придумать что-то свое будет еще труднее для меня. А вы не могли бы представить код функции `reliable_send`? Я был бы благодарен за это, сложно понять механизм на словах

Comment: Автор! Нашёл ответ ??? У меня та же самая проблема... И курс похоже мы один и тот же проходим, судя по коду)

Comment: Да, я немного похимичил с кодированием байтов и json, и у меня все получилось. Методом проб и ошибок. А вот курс лучше не палить)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@KonstantinSkokov дал Вам правильную наводку. Предлагаю Вам для решения этой проблемы использовать механизм [Chunked transfer encoding](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

---

Пусть максимальная длина куска будет `0xffff` (укладывается в 2 байта). Таким образом код для отправки данных будет выглядеть так:

```py
def reliable_send(self, data: bytes) -> None:
    """
    Функция отправки данных в сокет
    Обратите внимание, что данные ожидаются сразу типа bytes
    """
    # Разбиваем передаваемые данные на куски максимальной длины 0xffff (65535)
    for chunk in (data[_:_+0xffff] for _ in range(0, len(data), 0xffff)):
        self.connection.send(len(chunk).to_bytes(2, "big") # Отправляем длину куска (2 байта)
        self.connection.send(chunk) # Отправляем сам кусок
    self.connection.send(b"\x00\x00") # Обозначаем конец передачи куском нулевой длины
```

---

Вспомогательная функция приёма определённого количества байт

```py
def readexactly(self, bytes_count: int) -> bytes:
    """
    Функция приёма определённого количества байт
    """
    b = b''
    while len(b) < bytes_count: # Пока не получили нужное количество байт
        part = self.connection.recv(bytes_count - len(b)) # Получаем оставшиеся байты
        if not part: # Если из сокета ничего не пришло, значит его закрыли с другой стороны
            raise IOError("Соединение потеряно")
        b += part
    return b
```

---

Функция приёма данных:

```py
def reliable_receive(self) -> bytes:
    """
    Функция приёма данных
    Обратите внимание, что возвращает тип bytes
    """
    b = b''
    while True:
        part_len = int.from_bytes(self.readexactly(2), "big") # Определяем длину ожидаемого куска
        if part_len == 0: # Если пришёл кусок нулевой длины, то приём окончен
            return b
        b += self.readexactly(part_len) # Считываем сам кусок
```

---

*>>А еще эти decode, encode, base64... я успел запутаться в них миллион раз, пока писал код. Хотелось бы понять также, как, и можно ли вообще упростить это?* - `base64` нужен для кодирования любых байт в байты, которые можно смаппить на printable ascii символы, я не вижу у Вас задачи, для которой это бы потребовалось.

Comment: Спасибо, это чудесно работает с файлами. Вот только в моем коде требуется также отправлять и списки и строки, поэтому json мне был очень нужен, оказывается. Но ладно, я не осветил этот нюанс в вопросе, так что все в порядке. Правда теперь я себе еще больше проблем сделал, но ничего

Comment: @МихаилМуратов Кодируйте `json` и отправляйте, ничего сложного нет.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, дело в строке `data = self.connection.recv(1024)`
1024 - как раз один мегабайт

Вот тут похожая проблема, может поможет:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459499/what-is-the-proper-way-of-sending-a-large-amount-of-data-over-sockets-in-python

Comment: Проблема описана раздел Using a Socket тут  https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/sockets.html#using-a-socket

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Жаль компьютера нет рядом, не могу проверить ваши решения. Поэтому пока что оставляю вопрос открытым. Еще очень хотелось бы разобраться с decode, encode, base64 и получить код, работающий конкретно для моей задачи

Comment: Это здорово, что хотите разобраться. Жаль нет свободных серверов - для проверки кода.